# Re-sizing a div tag

Tags: asp.net, html

To begin with, I have seen a few similar questions to the one I am about to ask but none of them answer the question I have.

I have a div tag and have increased the height to 100%. However the div tag is remaining the same size?

My first question is why?
and my second question is: How to get the dive tag to respond the size I want?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Try to remove the style from body tag and place it in the form tag. Notice the difference? Your div is child of form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Div tag height 100% is equal to the height of the container that the Div is inside.  Try setting a min-height in your CSS if you are wanting to achieve a minimum set size for the Div.

```
{
min-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have heard that this only works in later browsers. How would I do this for older browsers?

Comment: "later browsers" means "IE7 and newer", do you care about IE6?

Comment: To do this in newer browsers, set a height: 123px; and if the contents of the div overflows this size then the Div should expend to cater to this.  Its probably an 'bad' exploit, but its one that works.

Comment: Sorry, mistake above, Older browsers not newer.

Answer (score 3):

If the height of the parent element is `auto`, then a percentage height is also treated as `auto`.

The height of the `html` element is not specified in your CSS, so it is `auto`.

The height of the `body` element is specified as `100%` but is the child of `html` so that becomes `auto`

The height of the `div` element is specified as `50%` but it is the child of `body`, so that also becomes `auto`.